# Makefile works in Linux but not Windows - can't find header files

Tags: linux, windows, makefile

Reasonably straight forward makefile. I'm trying to build an .so and a .dll to link to another program and the Linux version has gone completely smoothly. However, I receive a strange error when compiling in Windows

```
make: *** No rule to make target '/L/folder/folder/include/header.h',
needed by 'obj/file.o'.  Stop.
```

Which implies it can't find "header.h" for some reason because it tries to build it.

I have this bit of code to determine the platform (ugly, I know)

```
ifeq ($(PLT), lnx32)
INC_DIR = /mnt/L/folder/folder/include/
TARGET = lnx32/libmine.so
endif
ifeq ($(PLT), win32)
INC_DIR = /L/folder/folder/include/
TARGET = win32/libmine.dll
endif
```

Some even uglier makefile code to compile file.o

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/file.o:  $(INC_DIR)/header.h $(INC_DIR)/another_header.h $(SRC_DIR)/file.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(SYS5FLAG) -c $(SRC_DIR)/file.c -o $@ -I$(INC_DIR)
```

Not sure if it's relevant, but L is a network drive, I'm using Debian through VNC and msys in Windows. Does anything have an idea what could be going on? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**:

I changed

INC_DIR = /L/folder/folder/include/

to

INC_DIR = L:\produkter\RD\shared\include

to see what would happen and it gives a ton of

```
Cannot export y_varde: symbol not found
./obj/file.o: In function `some_function':
/mnt/L/folder/folder/./src/file.c:191: undefined reference to     `vsprintf'
```

errors. It's strange that it's looking at /mnt/ though as it really shouldn't be (in Windows).

** UPDATE 2 **

Okay, the problem was due to old object files from the Linux build. Instead of rebuilding them for Windows, it assumed they were the "correct" ones and tried to link them which obviously won't work. Still have an error though, but it seems more manageable, something to do with paths...

```
l:\foloder\folder/./src/somefile.c:1821: undefined reference to `debug'
```

Comment: *Does* `/L/folder/folder/include/header.h` exist? Because that doesn't look like a Windows path to me...

Comment: It does exist. I'm using MingW so you can use both Linux and Windows paths. I tried switching to a Windows style path and it gave even stranger errors. Will update question with them.

Comment: Your `ifeq` has an extra space, it is comparing `$(PLT)` with `" lnx32"` and `" win32"` (with a space at the start).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I fixed that, but there is still no difference.  Could have it have something to do with write permissions? If I type into the mingw terminal,

`cd /L/folder/folder/include/`
`ls `

I see my header.h. And the exact same makefile works from a Linux terminal. But in Windows, it doesn't see it...'